# Select every first and fourht(last) div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to select every first and fourth `div` with the `:nth-child` selector to add a specific style to it ?

```css
.main{
  width:460px;
  height:240px;
}
.box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
}

/*I tried */

.box:nth-child(n+4),.box:first-child{
  margin:10px 10px 10px 0;
}

.box:nth-child(4n){
  margin:10px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="box"></div> <!-- margin-left:0px -->
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div> <!-- margin-right:0px -->
  <div class="box"></div> <!-- margin-left:0px -->
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div> <!-- margin-right:0px -->
</div>
```

The second code works, but I am having trouble with the first ?

How to select every **first** and **last** div in the row (rows contains **four divs**)?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnQZU/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
.box:nth-child(4n+1)
```

That should include the first (`+1`) element and then every fourth (`4n`).

Answer (score 5):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jnQZU/1/)

4n will select 4, 8, 12 ....

4n+1 will select 1, 5, 9, 13, ...

Using a formula (an + b). Description: a represents a cycle size, n is a counter (starts at 0), and b is an offset value.

```
.box:nth-child(4n){
    margin:10px 0px 10px 10px;
}

.box:nth-child(4n+1){
   margin:10px 10px 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/jnQZU/2/

```
.box:nth-child(4n){
    background: blue;
}

.box:nth-child(4n+1){
    background: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/cJwVc/

```
.box:nth-child(4n+1){
   background-color:yellow;
   margin-left:0;
}

.box:nth-child(4n){
   background-color:blue;
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need IE8 or below support, than you should use the selector in Jquery. Using your example:

```
$('.box:nth-child(4n+1)').css('background-color', 'yellow');
```